# Autocomplete with chips not working in my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete, tags

I cannot fathom what I'm doing wrong here. I copied the code I have directly from this codepen: https://codepen.io/jcarlos17/pen/xqYzzX  where it is working correctly. I'm importing JQuery and there are no errors in the log. The input text bar shows up, I can type into it and when I hit return that text is turned into tags but it doesn't autocomplete at all.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
  <title>blah</title>


  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css">
  <link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/animate.css') }}">
  <link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/style.css') }}">
  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <!-- Navigation Bar --
    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
 ------->
<!-- Page introduction box -->
<div class="chips-autocomplete"></div>
  </body>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){


            $('.chips-autocomplete').material_chip({
                secondaryPlaceholder: 'Ingrese síntomas',
                placeholder: '+Síntoma',
                autocompleteData: {
                    'DEBILIDAD': null,
                    'DIARREA': null,
                    'ABDOMEN AGUDO': null,
                    }
                    });
  });

  </script>

</html>
```

I'm going a bit crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You load the wrong script version,
Instead of https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/**0.97.8**/js/materialize.min.js

try to load: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/**0.98.0**/js/materialize.min.js

(changes are in bold)

Comment: Right, it works like that in the code pen but not in my code. That's where I'm confused. If you copy and paste my code into an html file and run it you will see it's not working.

Comment: Do you happen to know where I can find the documentation for what options I can add to this material_chip function? This is all I could find: https://materializecss.com/chips.html but not only do these options not work, but the options that are working for me, like autocompleteData, are't listed.